# System rebooting while running hadoop mapreduce example

Tags: java, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

I am trying to follow the hadoop installation from here >> [installing hadoop 2.6.0 in Pseudo-distributed mode](http://zhongyaonan.com/hadoop-tutorial/setting-up-hadoop-2-6-on-mac-osx-yosemite.html.)

I am able to start my **HDFS** and **YARN** successfully on my **ubuntu 16.04 LTS** and the **jps** command is also returning :

9026 NodeManager

7348 NameNode

9766 Jps

8887 ResourceManager

7507 DataNode.

However, when i'm trying to run the examples provided with the hadoop binaries using the command :

**bin/hadoop jar share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.6.0.jar grep input output 'dfs[a-z.]+'**,

My system is rebooting and i am not able to find the clue as why is this happening becoz it's even giving any error before rebooting.

Your help will be much appreciated as i'm trying to run this from last 2 days.

**NOTE :** I have Oracle JDK 1.7.0_79 installed on my system

Comment: We cannot possibly tell what is happening on your system without a lot more information. For starters, show us the contents of the system log at the time of the reboot, as well as any other logs created by Hadoop.

Comment: @JimGarrison i'm new to Linux as well as hadoop, so i would be gr8ful if you can tell me which log files to look into

Comment: @JimGarrison, Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the behaviour was due to low memory issues. The moment i cleaned up some space on my system and did the steps again, it ran succesfully.

However, i'm not 100% sure about it.